# How to add tags between tags in html using selenium web driver python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

I want to insert a formatted text like  **bold**  in a text editor/text box on a website how would I do that?

I tried this :

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].AdjacentHTML('beforebegin', arguments[1])", node, <'strong> bold </'strong>)
```

However, this seems to add adjacent to the HTML not inside the text box.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with js method 'setAttribute':

```
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",node, "font-weight: bold");
```

Comment: i have html how can i add html to it the html contains attributes like <strong> <ul> etc

Comment: But isn't your purpose to change web element style?